# Text Highlighting - Content Editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, contenteditable, rich-text-editor

I've been experimenting with contenteditable fields in javascript. As you can probably guess, I'm trying to build a WYSIWYG editor. Piecing together answers I found on Stack Overflow, I managed to build this [test case](http://jsbin.com/kuguz/1/edit). The test case's job is to manually and programmatically highlight text and embolden it. There is just one small problem. If you click the "bold" button once, a substring is highlighted and subsequently made bold. However, if you click it again, it prompts an error:

```
"Error: Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': There is no child at offset 12.
at Error (native)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (http://run.jsbin.io/runner:15:13)
at HTMLDocument.oa (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js:18:373)
at HTMLDocument.c.event.handle (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js:55:307)
at HTMLDocument.j.handle.o (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js:49:363)"
```

After the first button press, the text field representing the WYSIWYG editor's content contains the following:

```
Some text he<span style="font-weight: bold;">re for y</span>ou to bold
```

Upon testing (by outputting the first child's length), my hypothesis is that it's trying to highlight only the first part - "Some text he." Further testing, including commenting out the statement to embolden the selection, confirmed this, I believe. In fact, when this is commented out the editor works well.

I searched on Google and Stack Exchange, yet partially due to my ignorance as to why this is happening I could find nothing.

My question is therefore - why is this error appearing, and what can I do to avoid it and reach my goal of programmatically highlighting and embolding this text?

Comment: Why are you giving `range.setStart` and `range.setEnd` solid numerical offsets?

Comment: Simply to manually highlight the part enclosed by those values. Only for experimentation/learning reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your linked demo code, you're setting the range with this code:

```
range.setStart(mainDiv.firstChild, 12);
range.setEnd(mainDiv.firstChild, 20);
```

But `mainDiv.firstChild` is the first text node of main div. On initial run that text node is

```
Some text here for you to bold
```

After the first run that text node gets broken into three pieces: 1 before the bold, one inside the bold, and one after.

```
Some text he<span style="font-weight: bold;">re for y</span>ou to bold
```

So your `mainDiv.firstChild` becomes

```
Some text he
```

For that reason the call to `range.setEnd(mainDiv.firstChild, 20)` is out of range.

To avoid this, don't hard-code your calls to setRange. Instead get your ranges directly from user selection (a very common case) or after inspecting the actual DOM just prior to making the call.

Comment: setEnd is not the problem, setStart is the problem.